An upper bound of the discrete Laplacian on a graph
On a scaled 2-dimensional grid $\epsilon\mathbb{Z}^2$, for any $f:\epsilon\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{R},$ we set the discrete Laplacian operator to be
$$\Delta_\epsilon f(x)=\epsilon^{-2}\sum_{y\in\epsilon\mathbb{Z}^2\\y\sim x}(f(y)-f(x)),$$
where $y\sim x$ means $y$ and $x$ are adjacent in $\epsilon\mathbb{Z}^2$.
Now let $k:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and compactly supported on the unit ball $B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^2.$ Let $\bar{k}(x)=k(x)$ for $x\in \epsilon\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus\{0\},$ and let $\bar{k}(0)=0.$ Consider the following quantity:
$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{\epsilon \mathbb{Z}^2}}\epsilon^2\Delta_\epsilon\bar{k}(x).\qquad(*)$$
The paper I'm reading says that since $k$ is compactly supported, $(*)$ is bounded by some constant $C,$ but I didn't understand why is it?
Since we are considering a scaled lattice, the points in the support of $k$ will still be of order $1/\epsilon^2$, which will bring $(*)$ to a very big value. How should we bound $(*)$ by a constant?
